# Banana Stand: Hide the green

Tags: script, javascript, topbar

Don't like your green rep notifications?

Hide them completely with Banana Stand:

#### [Banana Stand User Script Download Link](http://tommedley.com/files/banana-stand.user.js)

---

Alternatively, make the less intrusive with Banana Stand Lite:

#### [Banana Stand Lite User Script Download Link](http://tommedley.com/files/banana-stand-lite.user.js)